# What type of pressure or weight sensors are thin? (Arduino or R-Pi)

Tags: sensor, pressure

I want to know if a person is in a walking path of approx. 10x1,5 meters.

I thought on putting thin tables in the path and putting these sensors under each even table (to save some money): [https://www.amazon.com/Qisuw-Pressure-Sensor-FSR402-Sensitive-Resistor/dp/B07F1Q2Y6K/ref=sr_1_7?ie=UTF8&qid=1541179629&sr=8-7&keywords=force+sensitive+resistor+small](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07F1Q2Y6K)

However, for a 10 meters path, it would still be expensive.

Are there other options?

Edit: Ideally I would like something like this (the sensors to build, or the floor pad already built ready to connect)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what "these sensors" are so that we don't have to follow a link to understand your question. It also possibly makes the question still useful when the Amazon link dies. A photo is a big help too and will attract more readers.

Comment: There are plenty of sensors out there, look for load cell or strain gauge (you build the load cell with a strain gauge)

Comment: Do the sensors need to be tolerant to rain and dirt?

Comment: @crj11 yes, but I'm planning on sealing them. I want to make some kind of thin pad. Imagine a mousepad with those sensors, but larger

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps try using [Graphene Putty](https://graphene-flagship.eu/silly-putty-sensors).  There are directions for making your own [here](https://www.instructables.com/id/Goophene-Hypersensitive-Graphene-Sensors/).

Maybe an array of wires with a blob at the intersection of each wire would produce a change in resistance related to walking on the grid.  The bare portions of the wire would have to be offset to avoid the possibility of shorting by pressing them through the putty.

If you constrained the putty within a thin ring between two conductive strips, you could probably avoid the possibility of shorting the conductive strips when the crosspoint is compressed, but still measure some change in resistance.

And even if it doesn't work, you still get to play with Silly Putty(R).

[image: stretching to the limit]

> Graphene Flagship researchers from Trinity College Dublin in collaboration with the National Graphene Institute (NGI) at The University of Manchester, have used graphene to make a polysilicone polymer, known commonly as the novelty children’s material Silly Putty®, conduct electricity. Using this conductive polymer they found that they were about to create sensitive electromechanical sensors. The team’s findings have been published in the journal Science*.

Answer (score 0):

More details would be helpful.

- Do you need to know where the person is located in the 10m x 1.5m area?
- Is a low power laser at say average ankle height acceptable?

You could use a number of mirrors to bounce a laser beam in a criss-cross pattern across the area of concern and have a detector at the end.  If the beam is broken then something is in the target area.  You don't know exactly where it is but you know it is in the 10x1.5 area.

Comment: Added pictures. In the begginig, I do not need to know where the person is, but that would be good for the future and some calculations. In this first stage, I just need to know if there is a person (more than 14 kg for example).
I don't think a laser would be acceptable, because there might not be a place to install it, as it should be in the air, but also should point different directions and heights to match children and adults in the 1.5 meters wide pass